# PHP app connect to Oracle Database 11g - MVS 2013 & PHP Tools

Tags: php, oracle11g

As in title - I'm using MVS 2013 and I installed PHP Tools extension. I'm trying to connect to previously created databese (Oracle Database 11g).

```
<?php
$conn = oci_connect('system', 'mypass', 'localhost/XE');
if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
    }
?>
```

This code gives me error:

```
Call to undefined function oci_connect()
```

Comment: Do you have oci extension enabled in php.ini?

Comment: I don't have php.ini file at all. I created "PHP Web project" and I have only two files: project - PHP Project; index - PHP source file

Comment: Php doesn't run without a php.ini. Try to `echo phpinfo();` those are the contents of php.ini

Comment: Okay, it gave me an output. And in section "Configure Command" i found something containing "oci", but it's only something like this: "--with-pdo-oci=C:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk.shared"

Comment: So it's configured with PDO OCI there is your answer, use PDO to connect to oracle.

Comment: I have pretty common problem - could not find driver. How to solve it?

Comment: I edited php.ini and added some extension=... lines and it is not working.